# mod_rewrite by ISP name string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, remote-host

I have two servers - this one does not require `^` and backslash in order to work.
I want to redirect based on IP NAME not the IP number.
The (fictitious) IP Name is `74.125.227.104.cust.wildblue.net`

This works perfectly:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 74.125.227.104

RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This is wrong - the name is what I wish to catch and redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} cust.wildblue.net

RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Any help is VERY much appreciated!
Thank you

-David Dolores

Comment: remote_host is the hostname of whoever's hitting your server, and would only be available if there's a reverse DNS mapping for their IP. Maybe you want `HTTP_HOST`, which'd be the hostname they're requesting.

Comment: Thanks Marc, The ISP name has a boatload of different IPS (the first part of the "IP_NAME" entity in my tracker data) - My goal is to catch them all by using the common name string. If I use reverse DNS I still redirect based on individual IP right? tell me. I am not an expert on thyis subject.
do you have any suggestion